# Ionic React styles not rendering even after importing the styles in app.js

Tags: css, reactjs, ionic-framework, styles

I'm trying to use the ionic ui library(`@ionic/react`) to create the interface of my app. 
I've included the core.css file from ionic. 
But the components render without styles.

Following is the code in my App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { IonButton } from '@ionic/react';


import '@ionic/react/css/core.css';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <IonButton color="primary">Primary</IonButton>
      <IonButton color="secondary">Secondary</IonButton>
      <IonButton color="tertiary">Tertiary</IonButton>
      <IonButton color="success">Success</IonButton>
      <IonButton color="warning">Warning</IonButton>
      <IonButton color="danger">Danger</IonButton>
      <IonButton color="light">Light</IonButton>
      <IonButton color="medium">Medium</IonButton>
      <IonButton color="dark">Dark</IonButton>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

[check this image to see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYc7H.png)

dependencies versions: - 
"@ionic/react": "^6.0.9", 
"react": "^16.13.1",

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: @joseito, maybe include this as well - `import './theme/variables.css';`

Answer (score 5):

**NOTE**  https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/upgrading-to-ionic-6#react

Developers must import and call `setupIonicReact` even if they are not setting custom config.

In, App.tsx

```
import { setupIonicReact } from '@ionic/react';
 
setupIonicReact();
```